# Wordpress serve resources from a consistent URL

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When i test my wordpress website in **GTmetrix**, i get this result: 
**Serve resources from a consistent URL** 

The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 54.8KiB.

http://joangjermeni.joangjermeni.com/wp-content/plugins/themify-wc-product-filter/admin/themify-icons/fonts/themify.woff

http://joangjermeni.joangjermeni.com/wp-content/themes/themify-shoppe/themify/themify-icons/themify.woff

If i deactivate "Themify Product Filter" plugin, it is OK. I don't want to deactivate this plugin and i can not find these URLs in code. 
Can someone help me??

Comment: you can do nothing, you theme is using the same font as the plugin .. the only why to avoid this is to alter the theme or the plugin ... but it's not a big issue, you are not obliged to correct all the warning/errors given by Gtmetrix especially when it's a wordpress site. It's almost impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove below line from(plugin css) at the very top of file : \themify-wc-product-filter\admin\themify-icons\themify-icons.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'themify';
    src: url('fonts/themify.eot');
    src: url('fonts/themify.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/themify.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/themify.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/themify.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @kishan. It is ok now :)